# Executing C++ .exe From IIS in asp.net using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I am Executing Simple C++ (.exe) from Web Service in C#. It Works fine in Development Environment (in Visual Studio), But When I hosted in IIS, Process its not gets executed. I tried with Simple C# Console Application it works fine for me.
I Already Gave permissions to

1. Everyone
2. IUSR
3. Local Service
4. Network Service
5. Network
6. IIS_Users

from IIS through Edit permissions.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GETOCR()
    { 
        string OCROutput ="";
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\BSG\\ProcessOCR.exe", "12,13;964,15;964,634;9,634 \"C:\\BSG\\20150709_224156.jpg\" ");
        startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startinfo))
            {
                OCROutput = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                //Response.Write(OCROutput);



                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return OCROutput;
    }
```

Comment: Is your expectation that you will see it execute? This is not the case at is will run under the user account IIS is using and so will be isolated from you and your desktop. If the process launch failed an exception would be raised, is this the case? Does the exe appear in the all-users task list?

Comment: How do you know that it does not get executed? Do you get some exception in the C# code you showed? What exception?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the account of the Application Pool of your site. To do that click on your site in IIS (valid for IIS 7 and above), then click on **Basic Settings** in the **Actions** panel on the right. You will see the Application Pool name, remember it and click Cancel. After that go to the **Application Pools**, find the Application Pool you remember and select it. Click on the **Advanced Settings...** in the **Edit Application Pool** panel on the right. Look for the **Identity** in the **Process Model** section. Identity value is an account for which you need to set permission in **Security** tab for the file **C:\BSG\ProcessOCR.exe** (not for the site folder!) and the folder where this program will write/read files to/from (if any).

[image]